# How to pass value from Javascript to php variable on the second page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile

I have two pages. One that accepts input and stores it to a javascript variable. The other will receive the sent variable and store it to php variable so that i can forward it to the database.

here's the code of my first page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pricee= 0;
        var quants;
        function queue(num,str){
            this.pricee=num;
            this.quants=str;
            alert(num+" "+str);
        }
        function alertCurrentNumandStr(){
            alert("This is the latest: "+this.pricee+" "+this.quants);
        }
        function send(num){
             this.pricee=num;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><script type="text/javascript">var x=42, y="alive";</script><a href="#" onclick="queue(x, y);">42 Alive</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="alertCurrentNumandStr();">Get</a></li>

        <li><script type="text/javascript">var t=10;</script><a href="#" onclick="send(t);">Submit</a></li>
        <!--How to send this.pricee, this.quants to .php when clicking the Submit link(above)?-->
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And code on my secondpage:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
    $testNum= $_GET['pricee']
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
       echo "<h1>The num value </h1>";
       echo $testNum;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I pass the javascript variables to the second page when I click Submit?

Comment: There are 3 ways to do so: 1. Use a `GET` request (e.g. hyperlink to `test.php?price=12`) , 2. Use a form `POST` request (build a form and submit it, with action set to your PHP file name), 3. AJAX (too long to explain, learn from Google)

Comment: Are you restricted to only using javascript (no jQuery)? You can perform it in jQuery quite easily with the [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) or [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) functions.

Comment: @Raptor - yep, i read those methods. my problem now is, how can I trigger the page to send the request to the second page using javascript?

Comment: @Jake - i think so, 'cause I'm storing the values on javascript variables. Can Jquery method send the variables? I'm using jqm on my site btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your send function to this

```
  function send(quants){
window.location.href = "yourPhpPageUrl.com?price"+pricee+'qunatity' +quants;
            }
```

there will be no change in your `PHP file`. just give it a try

Comment: i understand this one but it doesn't load the second page. how can i transfer to the second page to verify if it received the value?

Comment: `window.location.href = "disp.php?price="+pricee+"&quantity=" +quants;`
is this right on my function?

Comment: Oh I got it `window.location.href = "http://localhost/disp.php?pricee="+pricee+"&quantity="+quants;`

Comment: aahh sorry wasnt on my system and I am glad that helped

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with simple GET Variable.

1. `<a href='yourphpfilename.php?price1=xxx&YOUR2ndvariable=xxx'>Click this</a>`
2. And by forwarding to the next php page, simple fetch this variables using

   $_GET['price1']; ...

Answer (score 0):

put your `li` tags in `form` tag like so:

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="GET">
    <ul>
        <li><script type="text/javascript">var price1=12, itn1="Mar";</script><a href="#" onclick="queue(price1, itn1);">Marinated $12</a></li>
        <li><script type="text/javascript">var price2=1, itn2="Kalamay";</script><a href="#" onclick="queue(price2, itn2);">Kalamay $1</a></li>
        <li><script type="text/javascript">var price3=5, itn3="coach Yeng";</script><a href="#" onclick="queue(price3, itn3);">Coach Yeng $5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="getPrice();">Get</a></li>

        <li><script type="text/javascript">var quantity=10;</script><a href="#" onclick="send(quantity);">Submit</a></li>
    </ul>
<input type="text" name="pricee" value="100">
<br>
Pricee:<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

i have assumed here that your php page is **action_page.php**

here `method = "GET"` tells the php page tha it has to receive the values as **get** requests.

In addition to this, `input type="submit"` before the closing `form` tag tells that you are using a **submit** event to sent the values in the `li` tags.

You have used a **pricee** tag in your php code (`$_GET("pricee")`). To match this request you must have an element with `name="pricee"`.

I have added that tag above.

Comment: Almost. You still keep OP's original Submit via JavaScript, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, i did this too, but how can I send the variable values? The php page can't receive any values since the sending variable is js and the receiving variable is php

Comment: @Raptor - i can submit them via php but the problem is js variables can't pass values to php variables in the same page.

Comment: I understand the new tag. But the values of each lis are constant and doesn't require the user to input price. Is there any way we can hide the text field and assign the js variable value to it?

Comment: @benziv please understand the difference of client-side scripting & server-side scripting